# Read incorrect data from UART in BananaPi

Tags: python, serial-port, uart

I am using a BananaPi to read UART data coming from a device. I know for sure what is the data generated by the device, it's the same 40 byte sequence sent in a loop, I know for sure because I mesure it with an oscilloscope. The data sent looks like(on the oscilloscope): 6A000496ED47.... 6A000496ED47....

I want to read this data in the BananaPi and I write a python script that looks like:

```
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = serial.Serial()
    connection.port = "/dev/ttyS2"
    connection.baudrate = 4000000
    connection.timeout = 1
    try:
        connection.open()
        print("serial port open")
        idx = 0
        while(idx < 10):
            data = connection.read(size=40)
            newData = data.encode('hex')
            print newData
            idx += 1
        connection.close()
    except:
        print("Opening serial error")
```

The output is:

> b777fbdc63e76....

So I get different sets of 40 bytes data on every of the 10 while loops.

Any ideea what might be wrong?

The serial setup is the same as in the oscilloscope meaning the baudrate is 4000000

Comment: `data = "" ; while connection.inWaiting() > 0 : data += binascii.hexlify(connection.read(1))` Who flush all serial data before received any data ? Where your `end delimiter` ? How to know initial starting index ?  This `?` char meaning all communication side !

Comment: I tried all sorts of serial configuration, I flushed the waiting data, hexify does the same as encode. I ran out of ideas of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: BananaPi  and uart 4MBaud ? Which technical document write this ? OS never reached to 4MBaud UART speed (Because OS is fuzzy and a human never detect this !)(of-course you do it with PCI-E card ). I imagine now "How an OS set a stable clock to USB host for 4Mbaud UART". You have a oscilloscope put a usb memory-stick , copy some file inside and check "Why my USB host got Fuzzy Data-rate ?".  You talking about `2.5 microsecond packet timer` of 4Mbaud(`8N1` pattern).  Okay, maybe take a high speed data from USB but how handle this data on real time ? With Panana PI ? Bad Joke !

Comment: Another point is most Industrial Product manufacturer  not provide 4MBaud speed on any UART converter(is special if found one).  Need buy a converter (ETH TO UART(20$)) maximum baud-rate is 1Mbaud(Inside a ARM-Cortex M4 >= 100Mhz MCU)